# Customising gradetable to group multiple-choice into 1 column with the `exam` class

Tags: exam, gradetable

I have written an exam with 2 Sections, the first of which contains 4 multiple choice questions and the 2nd contains Q5-7 which are free response with various parts.

Below is what I get using the default `\gradetable[h]`

[image]

I would like to customise it so that the first 4 questions are collapsed into 1 column with a heading such as MC in the question row and 4 in the points and then keep questions 5-7 as they are.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: as requested by @Mensch in the comments, the relevant code as it currently is:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\gradetable[h]
\begin{questions}
\question[1]
\question[1]
\question[1]
\question[1]
\question[12]
\question[12]
\question[12]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...